# Laravel 5.1 - Move uploaded file

Tags: php, file-upload, storage, laravel-5.1

I am trying to upload to the server a photo avatar. I have an ajax function that works correctly and uploads a photo to a tmp folder. The controller returns the original name and the tmp file path and saves to hidden fields.

What I need is when I save the model, move the tmp file from the tmp folder to the avatars folder (created by me inside public/images/avatars).

I have tried with `Storage::get($input['file_to_move'])`and get a `FileNotFoundException` (although the file really exists). How can I get a var `$file` with the file to do `$file->move($avatars_path)`.

Thanks In advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the problem is the default local disk point to the storage directory..

open config>filesystem
inside disks `array` insert this:

```
        'public' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => public_path(''),
        ],
```

now do this

```
Storage::disk('public')->get($input['file_to_move'])
```